# Which Chart Library is better for using in cordova for android and ios

Tags: javascript, cordova, charts, google-visualization

Hi actually i am having a requirement of displaying  data in table format and as well as in charts format .And i tried google charts and implemented in cordova and  it is not working in ios (Not displaying the chart). so please suggest me which type of chart lib is better for use in cordova ios and android and chart lib prefernce is open source

Answer (score 1):

This is your library: [Chart.js](http://1stwebdesigner.com/chart-js-library/)

It is not necessary to install additional cordova plugin, just include the lib ;)

Here you can check some [demos](http://1stwebdesigner.com/demos/chartjs/line.html).